# How can I get the category name of a post without a link?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

Simple question. I'm creating a wordpress theme and I want to display the post category name inside a `<h1>` tag.

If I used the_category(""); wordpress outputs a linkable category name.

Since I'm already on that categories page, I don't want the category name to be linkable, instead, I only want it displayed as plain text.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: tip: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com is the place for WordPress Questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `<?php single_cat_title( ); ?>`

you can see doc here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title

Answer (score 0):

[`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) will get you all the post's categories:

> Returns an array of objects, one object for each category assigned to the post. This tag may be used outside The Loop by passing a post id as the parameter.

as a general rule in the Wordpress Codex, `get_xyz()` will return the value, where `xyz()` will output it.